# Changing password doesn't work

Tags: oracle, authentication

I need to login to a database. I have good credentials, but when I was trying to login with SQL Developer, I got this error message:

> ORA-28001: the password has expired

Then I tried to login with SQL*Plus, which worked fine, I connected successfully and I was asked to change my password.

So I typed in a new password and then retyped it. Then I got other message:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon failed

Can you help me how can I change this password? I don't have administrative permissions.

Comment: Does your version of SQL*Plus match the database server?  You may see strange behavior if you connect to an 11g database from an older client.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the following:

At first login as SYSDBA and check the ACCOUNT_STATUS of your user (SYSTEM in the sample below).

```
> sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> select username, account_status, lock_date from dba_users where username='SYSTEM';
```

If this statement doesn't return a record, then your account does not exist.

If the account is locked (maybe because you entered a wrong password several time) then you have to unlock the account:

```
SQL> alter user SYSTEM account unlock;
```

To reset the password you can use this statement:

```
SQL> alter user SYSTEM identified by NEW_SYSTEM_PWD;
```

If you are working with a development system, then you can ignore case sensitive logons and make sure passwords never expire again:

```
SQL> alter system set sec_case_sensitive_logon=false scope=both;
SQL> alter profile default limit password_life_time unlimited;
```

See Oracle documentation for further infos regarding [DBA_USERS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4174.htm)